# Python sockets - stop stripping carriage return from UDP datagram

Tags: python, sockets

I have a Python script that is reading an ASCII file (basically NMEA strings) and then broadcasting them over UDP using the basic socket library.

Every second a 'paragraph' of NMEA strings are send out with a header. The server expects each paragraph to begin with an empty line (specifically a \r\n, ie 0d 0a). I build my string appropriately ('\r\n' + paragraph). Looking at the string value in the debugger and converting the string to hex it is correctly prepended with 0d0a.

However, when I inspect the hex dump in Wireshark, it seems that 0d is being stripped out, presumably by the socket library, so the final datagram just has 0a. Which should be fine of course, except the server is hard-coded to expect 0d0a.

So, is there any way to force the socket library to keep the 0d hex character? The same thing happens when I run the client under Windows and Linux.

Comment: Quite a strange thing, usually "\n" gets converted to "\r\n" when communicating over a socket / serial port / ..

Comment: What exactly are you using to send the data? Can you show a few lines of code? The socket library by itself is 8-bit clean and will not alter bits, but you may be using an intermediary stream or file-like object which is doing universal-newline interpretation.

Comment: e.g., are you using `socket.makefile()` without mode `'wb'`?

Comment: `s = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )  
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)  
s.sendto(strToSend,(HOST, port))`

Comment: Post your code for opening the file, reading the file, and sending on socket.  I would guess they are being stripped when you read from input file.  Do you open the file as 'r' or 'rb'?

Comment: I just do `for line in open(currentFilename, 'rb').readlines():` to read the file. The newlines from the file get translated correctly, however at the start of each NMEA 'paragraph' I manually prepend a CR LF: `strToSend = '\r\n' + line[match.end():]` It's this step that is causing the problem. Even though the \r\n is prepended OK, at some stage between passing the string to sendto() and the datagram going out on the wire, the 0d on that extra CRLF is stripped. The 0d0a that are present in the original file is transmitted OK.

Python 2.7.2, win32 BTW.

Comment: Could you post the code that you are using to process the incoming packets and explain where it is failing?

Comment: The client program is a third party application written in C++ over which I have no control and can't modify. From looking at the source though, it's using something like `l_status = s_recv.find("\r\n");` to split the paragraphs and then process each individual NMEA string. So it'll process the first message OK, then fall over.

Comment: So, in that case if you aren't stripping the original `\r\n`, the receiving program will see (when treated as a stream) `\r\n<NMEA string>\r\n\r\n<NMEA string>\r\n...`. That's what it is expecting? Also, when you say an "empty line" - a single `\r\n` pair is not an empty line unless followed immediately by another `\r\n`.

Comment: @Caligari - don't keep adding comments here.  Just update your question with your code and with these details.

Answer (score 2):

You *need* to edit your original post with *actual code* so we can get a handle on what might be going wrong.

This is a short demonstration on Python 2.6 which does not have magic newline munging:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
>>> s.sendto('\r\nSOME TEXT HERE', ('127.0.0.1',9999))
```

And in another terminal:

```
$ nc -ul 9999 | od -c
0000000   \r  \n   S   O   M   E       T   E   X   T       H   E   R   E
```